# Hover color for a not changing only background

Tags: html, css

So since I have been trying so hard to make the h4 color change from #333333 to #ffffff while making the background change from #ffffff to #028041

here is a snippet of my code

```css
.pnl-heading {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 11px 43px 13px 43px;
}

.pnl-heading a {
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #333333;
}

.pnl-default .pnl-heading:hover, .pnl-default .pnl-heading.active {background:#028041; color: #FFFFFF}
```

```html
<div class="pnl-default">
  <div class="pnl-heading active">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a href="#">Group 1</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pnl-default">
  <div class="pnl-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a href="#">Group 1</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to target `a`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .pnl-heading:hover a{
          color: fff;
     }

     .pnl-heading:hover {
          background: #028041;
      }
```

Comment: @Ifaruki CSS properties should be all lowercase. Edited to reflect

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#pnl-heading {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 11px 43px 13px 43px;
}

#pnl-heading {
  background: #028041;
  border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 11px 43px 13px 43px;
}

#panel-title{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#panel-title:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Hope this helps